# How to make an Effect in ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I've created a simple effect in ngrx using [this](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/intro.md) as a template. My code is slightly different:

`

```
@Effect()
 addSeries$ = this.actions$
     //Listen for the 'ADD_SERIES' action
     .ofType(GraphsActions.ADD_SERIES)
     //use that payload to construct a data query
     .map(action => action.payload)
     .switchMap(payload => this.http.get(/*making a url with payload here*/)
     // If successful, dispatch success action with result
     .map(res => ({ type: GraphsActions.SERIES_DATA, payload: res.json() }))
     // If request fails, dispatch failed action
     .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: 'FAILED' })));
```

`

In the final map I want to have the payload contain information from the initial payload from the first map, how would that be accomplished?

I'm still having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how some of this streaming stuff works, so if someone could provide an english explanation of what exactly is happening here would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ngrx, an`Effect` allows you to trigger side effect(s) when some action has been dispatched.
That said, a simple effect workflow would be :
- Dispatch`FETCH_PERSON_DETAILS` (with payload : `{personId: string}`). In the reducer, for that person, just set a boolean `isFetchingDetails` to true.
That allows you to show a spinner (for example) while loading details of that person.
- From an effect, catch that action and launch an HTTP request to get the details.
- Once you've got the response, dispatch `FETCH_PERSON_DETAILS_SUCCESS` with the data from the response
- If an error happened while fetching the data, dispatch `FETCH_PERSON_DETAILS_FAILED` with only the `personId` (that you can find in the previous `action.payload`)

Here, your problem is simply the indentation of you code.
If we re-indent it :

```
@Effect()
addSeries$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(GraphsActions.ADD_SERIES)
  .map(action => action.payload)
  .switchMap(payload => this.http.get(/*making a url with payload here*/)
    .map(res => ({ type: GraphsActions.SERIES_DATA, payload: res.json() }))
    .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: 'FAILED' })));
```

We can see that the `map` is into the `switchMap`. Thus from the map, you have acccess to the `switchMap` parameter(s) --> `payload`.

So in order to have the content from the previous payload + the response, you might do :

```
.switchMap(payload => this.http.get(/*making a url with payload here*/)
  .map(res => ({ type: GraphsActions.SERIES_DATA, payload: {action.payload, ...res.json()} }))
```

(or re-arrange the payload as you want)

Comment: Ohhh thanks! I should've at least tried using the original payload in the map, but I had convinced myself that I couldn't. Thanks for the explanation too, that really clears up Effects!